# Is this form of epsilon delta version of Limit valid?

Tags: limits

Just a thought came in my mind , i understand the original def of epsliom delta version of limit . Why cant the limit definition be based on" for every delta there exits epsilon thing such that..."? Why the mathematicians give def for "every epsilon there exists delta such that..", was there some kind of contradiction in that def for some  functions where it was not valid? Hence the epsilon to delta was selected ?

Comment: Are you sure you understood the definition?

Comment: Or maybe this will, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3554346/in-the-epsilon-delta-definition-what-is-wrong-if-i-said-given-delta-there-ex

Comment: Ty there was already one answer

Comment: The bottom line is that you can define whatever you like but it may be useless. The conventional definition of limits is useful. Yours is useless.